# Include text file in a batch file... (like php include but with batch)

Tags: windows, xaml, batch-file, text

i have a batch file which i've just got working and inside it is this:

```
 for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (people.csv) do (
  echo  ^<Grid Background^="Red" x:Name^="ContentPanel" Margin^="12,0,12,0"^>^<StackPanel Margin^="20" Background^="Blue" PointerPressed^="commonHandler"^>^<TextBlock x:Name^="firstTextBlock" FontSize^="30" ^> %%a ^</TextBlock^>^<TextBlock x:Name^="secondTextBlock" FontSize^="30" ^> %%b ^</TextBlock^>^<TextBlock x:Name^="thirdTextBlock" FontSize^="30" ^> %%c ^</TextBlock^>^</StackPanel^>^</Grid^> >>%%a.xaml
)
```

That is a just an xaml file that i cut out and echoed into the batch file, but the people that are going to use this system aren't IT literate and so i need to get rid of all that code and put it in an external file and then include that text file into this file so then the users can edit the external text file instead of the batch file.

If that didnt make any sense, im sorry...

Ive tried putting it in another for loop but that didnt do anything...

I sort of thought of it as a 'php include' sort of thing?

Thank you

Comment: No, you didn't make any sense.

Comment: Note that accepting previous answers is polite, it helps your reputation, and lets future readers know which solution to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
call included.bat %*
rem do other stuff...
```

this will execute included.bat with the same arguments as the current file, and it will execute exactly when it is called. be sure to specify the full path. also, you can pass any arguments you want, or none.